How to set k value using knnsearch in Matlab
I have a code to classify an image.
training1 = xlsread('Data Train');

% mentions the location of the training data matrix in the excel file
training = [training1(:,1) training1(:,2) training1(:,3) training1(:,4) training1(:,5) training1(:,6) training1(:,7) training1(:,8) training1(:,9) training1(:,10) training1(:,11) training1(:,12) training1(:,13) training1(:,14) training1(:,15) training1(:,16) training1(:,17) training1(:,18) training1(:,19) training1(:,20) training1(:,21) training1(:,22) training1(:,23) training1(:,24)];

% mentions input data variables
Z=[MeanR MeanG MeanB MeanH MeanS MeanV VarRed VarGreen VarBlue VarH VarS VarV RangeR RangeG RangeB RangeH RangeS RangeV sdR sdG sdB sdH sdS sdV];

%perform knn classification
result = knnsearch(training,Z);

if (result>=1 && result<=20)
    set(handles.EditBox,'string','Raw');
elseif (result>=21 && result<=40)
    set(handles.EditBox,'string','Undercook');
elseif (result>=41 && result<=60)
    set(handles.EditBox,'string','Cook');
elseif (result>=61 && result<=80)
    set(handles.EditBox,'string','Rotten');
end

Does the knnsearch syntax only default k with a value of 1?
How can I get the k value in knnsearchto be 5?
when I try to change it to
k = 5;
result = knnsearch(training,Z,'K',k); 

the system does not display the classification result.

Careful with the tagging. python and C++ seem utterly irrelevant to this question. They are attracting additional eyes, but those eyes are not likely to be able to give much help (unless they are also monitoring matlab), and in the case of a weak question, are likely to add additional down and close votes. project doesn't seem to add anything to the question either.

Is time to learn to use the debugger (which is really easy to do in MATLAB), and to figure out what is going on. You get some result value (because the function is documented to always return some value), but the code that checks it and updates the text in the GUI doesn’t recognize the value. Maybe the value is not what you expect it to be? What is it then? The debugger will tell you! Set a break point, and look at the value when the program gets to that step.

When you increase the k to 5 or any value greater than 1, the output result will be a vector containing the indices of the k nearest neighbours rather than a single index. This is why your code doesn't work as expected when you set k = 5.
I would highly recommend utilizing the debugger, here is a help center page and a MATLAB video to get you started.
